Google sheets - data validation or protection
(Tee Time Sheet) I have a Google sheets app (attached) that allows golfers to indicate whether they intend to play golf on a given date.
In column "EL" four golfers have already signed up ("I" for in & "O" for out, see row 30 for total golfers that are in (4)). I would like to restrict entry into any blank cells in column "EL" (golf courses allow a maximum of 4 golfers per group).
In the column "EM" only two golfers have signed up, such that I would like to allow entry into blank cells (with "I") up to the point that the the total number of golfers is 4. Then restrict entry as in column "EL".
I am running out of things to try using data validation and protection. So far a solution has escaped me.
Tee Time Sheet

I have a Google sheets app (attached) Sorry, no sign of any attachments.

Thanks for adding the attachment. I wasn't expectating an image; the Help Tour (How do I ask a good question?) is pretty specific about this. "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. —copy or type the text into the question."

This question is similar to: Stop edit of a cell based on the value of a cell in the same row. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
